# Not being able to change the value of input tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to set the default value of input tag to a state but when I do so I'm unable to change anything in the input tag, The text just gets stuck, Here is an example of my code:

```
function RandomScreen(){
    const [State, SetState] = useState()
    // Make API call to set the state
    const inputValue = State
    return(
        <input onChange={handleState} value={inputValue} />
    )
}
```

I'm using `onChange` but did not want to include it to reduce noise and to minimize code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `onChange` function to change value of `input`

Try something like below:-

```
function RandomScreen(){
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState('');
   
    return(
        <input value={inputState} onChange={(e) => setInputState(e.target.value)}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm using ```onChange``` but did not want to include it to reduce noise and to minimize code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the changes in Input because you are making the input controlled and not updating the state.

Try doing this:

```
function RandomScreen(){
    const [input, setInput] = useState();
    const onChange = e => {
      // call API here
    setInput(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <input value={input} onChange={onChange} />
    )
}
```

Read more about controlled components here:https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

For making API call you can also take use of `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I'm using ```onChange``` but did not want to include it to reduce noise and to minimize code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write an event handler called `onChange` which will update the state as you type. Here is a slightly changed and updated code -

```
function RandomScreen(){
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
// Make API call to set the state
return(
    <input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)} />
)
```

}

Comment: I'm using ```onChange``` but did not want to include it to reduce noise and to minimize code.

Comment: You can change your code according to the one which is mentioned in the comments. It will surely work